# How to specify a return type if it is behind a private module?

Tags: module, rust

```
fn connect_tls() -> Result<rustls::stream::Stream<rustls::client::ClientSession, TcpStream>, Box<dyn Error>> {}
```

gives

```
module `stream` is private

private module

module `client` is private

private module
```

Can the type somehow be inferred?

Comment: if you don't need the exact type, but rather its trait, then maybe you can do `-> Result<impl io::Write>` or `-> Result<Box<dyn io::Write>>`, though I'm not sure if such would compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modules `client` and `stream` are private, but `client::ClientSession` and `stream::Stream` are [both](https://github.com/ctz/rustls/blob/d3eeeb6a2de5f641929e3a314305234d0facb4ff/rustls/src/lib.rs#L273) [exported](https://github.com/ctz/rustls/blob/d3eeeb6a2de5f641929e3a314305234d0facb4ff/rustls/src/lib.rs#L278) by the `rustls` crate at the top level. You should be able to just write this as:

```
fn connect_tls() -> Result<rustls::Stream<rustls::ClientSession, TcpStream>, Box<dyn Error>> {}
```

The [documentation for rustls](https://docs.rs/rustls/0.18.1/rustls/struct.Stream.html) doesn't mention those private modules at all, so you will be just fine by using types as shown in the docs.